# What does "Timed out trying to acquire capabilities data" mean coming from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, gh-unit

This is a pretty silly situation: I'm using [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) to test an app and I'm running those tests outside the simulator [according to the instructions](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_command_line.html).

Everything was great for a long time, but we're getting in to a situation now where I'm getting this mysterious log message in the console coinciding with a pause of several seconds rather frequently in my test suite:

```
Timed out trying to acquire capabilities data.
```

This is a little disconcerting if only because it's only happening on one machine; everything is as smooth as can be everywhere else I run this test suite. I can totally believe that there's hardware missing or failing on this machine, but does anybody have any idea where to go next in debugging this? Google has never heard the phrase before.

Answer (score 5):

We found this to be a problem when the unit tests are the first thing run after reboot.

While it would be nice to know the cause more fundamentally, we were able to fix it by having the simulator run on login on our continuous integration machine.